# Armour For Warriors Returning From The Deathwatch

Tags: warhammer-40k, space-marines

The Deathwatch is not a normal chapter of Adeptus Astartes, they recruit from other chapters who serve on the Deathwatch before rotating back into their own chapter.

While serving in the Deathwatch they wear their original chapter symbol on their right shoulder and their Deathwatch on the right pauldron.

[image]

However, once a warrior returns to their own chapter does their armour revert to normal or do they carry some insignia from their time in the Deathwatch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have one example of this in the Warhammer+ series *Angels of Death*, following a Blood Angels squad. One of the seargants, Kazarion, used to serve in the Deathwatch:

> Kazarion is a Blood Angels Sergeant who has recently returned to his Chapter, after serving in the Deathwatch.
>
> From the Lexicanum [article on Kazarion](https://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Kazarion)

At S1E3 at timestamp 3min, 25 sec, the following appears:

[image: Kazarion (right)]

His left shoulder plate has clearly the inquisitorial I of the Deathwatch:

[image: Inquisitorial I of the Deathwatch]

They therefore (can) keep some part of their Deathwatch armour, identifying those that have served in the Deathwatch. As we don't have a lot of examples of ex-Deathwatch Astartes, it is unknown (to me) if they can keep it, it requires maybe some special merits to earn this or all Space Marines having served in the Deathwatch will get it and are maybe even obliged to wear it. This might also highly depend on the chapter.

For some chapters, like the Space Wolves, serving in the Deathwatch is considered a reprimand and they therefore will probably not wish to display that after they've returned.

Comment: Great - thanks, So DW on the left and what on the right? Chapter or squad markings?

Comment: I'm trying to build a few DW vets in my army ;)

Comment: @Liath It would seem to be a standard shoulder guard: https://imgur.com/a/QrF9Uog

Answer (score 0):

All the former deathwatch marines keep their deathwatch shoulder pad, and wear it as a point of honor. (Chapter dependent, but that's the idea anyway.)  It's one of the reasons the tactical marine command set comes with a single deathwatch shoulder pad.

As for the armor as a whole, that's iffy with the new lore of specific deathwatch armor. The "traditional" lore was that a marine showed up to the Deathwatch wearing his armor, got some upgrades (DW shoulder pad, sometimes up-cycled to MkVIII armor if his chapter plate was particularly unsuitable for whatever reason), and wore that armor throughout his service and upon return to his chapter kept it.  If the armor was damaged, he would be issued replacements from Deathwatch stores that were generally MkVIII.  (The deathwatch RPG fluff mentions this, as does the Deathwatch Omnibus).

With the new lore in the latest codex and the new minis, it would appear that a marine is given a completely different set of specialized MkVIII armor.  Whether they're expected to arrive with their original chapter armor or not is conjecture.  However they are still allowed to wear the deathwatch shoulder pad after they return to their chapter.  Given that their "normal" plate is either in storage or left at home, one would assume that additional pieces of deathwatch armor would be less likely to come home with a returning DW veteran.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You could improve this answer by editing it to include some supporting evidence, such as an image, video link, or quote (with an accompanying link to any page the quote was sourced from).